# Issue with Multiple Column Pair Wise Subquery in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am working on practice problems from the following website:
https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/SQL/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-sql/seq-exercise-sql_social_query_core/

I have come up with two solutions for problem 7 which is as follows, "For each student A who likes a student B where the two are not friends, find if they have a friend C in common (who can introduce them!). For all such trios, return the name and grade of A, B, and C."

My first solution is as follows and returns the desired result when run using Oracle SQL:

```
select a.name, a.grade, b.name, b.grade, c.name, c.grade
  from highschooler a
  join highschooler b on a.id != b.id
  join highschooler c on a.id != c.id and a.id != b.id
  where (a.id, c.id) in (select id1, id2 from friends)
    and (b.id, c.id) in (select id1, id2 from friends)
    and a.id not in (select id1 from friends where id2 = b.id)
    and a.id in (select id1 from likess where id2 = b.id)
;
```

My second solution is identical, but replaces the condition which checks to see if student A and B are friends with a multiple column pair wise subquery. For some reason, this solution doesn't work:

```
select a.name, a.grade, b.name, b.grade, c.name, c.grade
  from highschooler a
  join highschooler b on a.id != b.id
  join highschooler c on a.id != c.id and a.id != b.id
  where (a.id,c.id) in (select id1, id2 from friends)
    and (b.id,c.id) in (select id1, id2 from friends)
    and (a.id,b.id) not in (select id1, id2 from friends)
    and a.id in (select id1 from likess where id2 = b.id)
;
```

To my understanding, both of these queries are identical, yet only the first solution works. It obviously has something to do with the following code from solution 2:

```
and (a.id,b.id) not in (select id1, id2 from friends)
```

Why does the second query fail?

The schema for this database can be found at the following link:
https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/socialdata.html

Comment: Words like "works", "doesn't work", "fail" have no meaning. In what way does your second query fail? Does it throw a syntax error? A runtime exception? Does it run but the result is wrong?

Comment: From the outset, there is a bug in both your versions. You have `a.id != b.id` twice, and instead you don't also check for `b.id != c.id`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and examples of desired output. Thanks.

Comment: PSB the output received from both the queries , its the same.
Can you please provide more details about your expectations of the output.

+--------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+-------+
| name   | grade | name      | grade | name    | grade |
+--------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+-------+

| Andrew |    10 | Cassandra |     9 | Gabriel |     9 |

| Austin |    11 | Jordan    |    12 | Andrew  |    10 |

| Austin |    11 | Jordan    |    12 | Kyle    |    12 |
+--------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+-------+